# Multi- to single-part on a subset of features

Tags: qgis, digitizing, multipart

I have a question about the multi-to single-part function.

How can I apply this process to a specific multipart?

I have several multiparts, but only want to resolve one of them into its objects. However, I fear with the tool that all multiparts will be resolved because I can only select my layer.
I've already looked into the field commands. It is just not clear to me how I should convey to him that he should only select a specific multiparts.

Answer (score 2):

1. Start edit
2. Select the polygon
3. Split feature parts

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! :)

Comment: Nice! If it worked please accpet my answer with the checkbox